# Media query changes not reflecting

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to control the width of the menu using media queries. Below is the one i am using for different resolutions.

```css
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
  .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
    width: 20%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;

}
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 500px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1100px) 
   and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
  .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
    width: 20%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;

}
}
@media  screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
 {

  .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
    width: 35%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;

}}

@media  screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
 {

  .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
    width: 25%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;

}}
```

even while changes the resolution it always takes the css which I have defined as default.

```css
.cbp-spmenu-vertical {
    width: 15%;
    /* height: 100%; 
    margin :50px;*/

    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I have the viewport meta tag in my html too.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Angular/css/landscape/ta-menu.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- App Body -->
<!-- <div id=map style="width: 100%"></div> -->
<div id="menu" class="cbp-spmenu-push">
    <div id="cbpspmenus1" class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" ng-class="{'cbp-spmenu-open':isActive}">
        <div id="tools">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Type To Filter" ng-model="search" class="searchMenu"></td>
                    <td><button id="home" class="homeButton"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2"></i></button></td>
                    <td><button id="keep-menu-open" class="pinColor"ng-click="openAndFixMenu"><i class="pinColor"></i></button></td>
                    <td><button id="open-left" class="toggleButton" ng-click="toggleMenu()"> <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="accordion">
            <accordion-menu ng-if="jsonstring.length>0" menu='jsonstring'></accordion-menu>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In another scenario I am using the media query based on different resolution to change the font size in my menu and that works fine. What could be wrong with the above media queries.

Comment: You shouldn't use code snippets if they don't actually run; There's a standard "code block" in the editor for that.

Comment: You should also include your HTML so we can see how your viewport tag is set up.

Comment: I assume your `.cbp-spmenu-vertical` class is placed before your media queries? Also, you mention "changing" the resolution. Did you mean to use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`? The latter will not be affected by resizing your browser window (I think).

Comment: @noahnu yes .cbp-spmenu-vertical is placed before the queries. By changing the resolution I meant was in debugger mode I changed the mode to ipad resolution and the changes didnt kick in.